# Issue custom elements with property panel not working bpmn io

Tags: javascript, bpmn.io

need a help please....

I have used https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/custom-elements example and it's work fine with custom elements. But when I add property panel then it starts giving an error **bo.get is not a function** and also it is not included custom elements in the downloaded XML.

Comment: You bootstrapped with the properties panel extension? When exactly do you get the bo.get error?

Comment: If **drag and drop** or **click** my own custom element.@MatthewYoung

Comment: Maybe custom rules are needed with drag/drop of custom elements. Just a guess. What does drag/drop have to do with the properties panel? Does drag/drop work without that panel?

Comment: If i removed property panel then custom rules worked. But problem is only with that panel. @MatthewYoung

Comment: Don't you need a properties provider? Check out this post also https://forum.bpmn.io/t/integrating-bpmn-js-properties-panel-with-bpmn-js-modeler/815